# Generic way of writing String.class, Long.class, Double.class in primitive and List type

Tags: java, class

Consider below code in Java. I'm writing these case for each primitive data types separately.

```
Method method;
switch (nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getValueTypeCase()) {
  case STR_VALUE:
    method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, String.class);
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getStrValue());
    break;
  case INT64_VALUE:
    method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, Long.class);
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getInt64Value());
    break;
  case STR_LIST:
    method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, String.class);
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getStrList());
    break;
  default:
    log.info("Does not match any datatype")
```

How can I change above code to something like below. Basically I want to club and minimise the code,

```
Method method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, Generic.class);
switch (nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getValueTypeCase()) {
  case STR_VALUE:
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getStrValue());
    break;
  case INT64_VALUE:
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getInt64Value());
    break;
  case STR_LIST:
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getStrList());
    break;
  default:
    log.info("Does not match any datatype")
```

Here, Generic.class does not works.

I've one another question. Consider below code,

```
Method method;
switch (nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getValueTypeCase()) {
  case STR_LIST:
    method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, String.class);
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getStrList());
    break;
  default:
    log.info("Does not match any datatype")
```

Here I'm getting warning message -> Argument is not assignable to 'java.lang.String'

How can I fix this. Can I write something like,

```
Method method;
switch (nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getValueTypeCase()) {
  case STR_LIST:
    method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, List<String>.class);
    method.invoke(cls_name, nameTimeValuePair.getValue().getStrList());
    break;
  default:
    log.info("Does not match any datatype")
```

Here, List<String>.class does not works.

Thanks for you inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
I dont know what is returned by `nameTimeValuePair.getValue()`, so I suppose it's instance of `ValueHolder` class. My idea based on using enum with fields instead of switch-case

```
public enum ReflectionType {

    STR_VALUE(String.class, ValueHolder::getStrValue),
    INT64_VALUE(Integer.class, ValueHolder::getInt64Value),
    //  other types
    ;

    ReflectiionType(Class<?> klass, Function<ValueHolder, Object> valueGetter) {
        this.klass = klass;
        this.valueGetter = valueGetter;
    }

    private final Class<?> klass;
    private final Function<ValueHolder, Object> valueGetter;

    public Class<?> getKlass() {
        return klass;
    }

    public Function<ValueHolder, Object> getValueGetter() {
        return valueGetter;
    }
}
```

Then your invoke logic shortens to

```
ValueHolder valueHolder = nameTimeValuePair.getValue();
ReflectionType type = valueHolder.getValueTypeCase();
Method method = cls_name.getClass().getMethod(ATTR_METHOD_NAME, type.getKlass());
method.invoke(cls_name, type.getKlass().cast(type.getValueGetter().apply(valueHolder)));
```

**2**. You can qualify static `.class` only by class name without generics. What about `List.class`?

**UPD:** Also minor tip - `cls_name` should be named like `clsName`. Java likes camelcase